# Taylor expand $\ln(x) - \ln(1-y)$ around$(\ln(x'),\ln(y'))$

Tags: taylor-expansion, partial-derivative

Can I taylor expand
$$\ln(x) - \ln(1-y)$$
around $(\ln(x),\ln(y'))$ such that I get

$$ \ln(x') - \ln(1-y') + \frac{\partial (\ln(x) -\ln(1-y))}{\partial \ln(x')} (\ln(x) - \ln(x')) + \frac{\partial (\ln(x) -\ln(1-y))}{\partial \ln(y')} (\ln(y) - \ln(y')) \tag{1}
$$
I was thinking that I can just choose to expand around the point $(\ln(x),\ln(y'))$ because I don't see how that would be different from $x',y'$, but I'm not sure if I can say $\ln(x) - \ln(x')$ instead of $x - \ln(x')$

Can someone comment or confirm or shoot me down?

Basically, I want to treat
$$\ln(x) - \ln(1-y)$$
as a function of the logs, $f(\ln(x),\ln(y))$ and then expand around $(\ln(x'),\ln(y'))$

Thanks.

Note: I am using prime notation to define points, not new variables.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're considering $x'$ and $y'$ as specific values of $x$ and $y$ or as a pair of new variables. The notation with primes seems to favour the latter interpretation, but the only way I can make sense of this is to consistently apply the former. Why does the constant term have $\ln(y')$ and not $-\ln(1-y')$? Perhaps it would help if you explicate how you expanded $f(\ln(x),\ln(y))$. Principally speaking, you can certainly treat the logarithms as the independent variables and expand in them, but as far as I can tell you haven't consistently done so.

Comment: (Part of what's confusing is that the partial derivatives seem to imply a two-dimensional coordinate transformation, but then you write that you expand around "the points $\ln(x')$ and $\ln(y')$" in the plural, and not "the point $(\ln(x'),\ln(y')$").

Comment: @joriki I am considering $x'$ and $y'$ as specific values. I probably should have used $x^*$ or some other notation to make it more clear, you are right. Also, I mean the point $((ln(x'),ln(y'))$, not *the pointS*. That was simply me being careless. Regarding why I have $ln(y')$ and not $-ln(1-y')$... I was considering that and I was also thinking that it should be $ln(1-y')$. I had a reason for writing $ln(y')$ instead, but upon thinking some more I have realized that my reasoning was incorrect. So thank you, for helping me clarify and for confirming that I can expand in logarithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write

$$
\ln x-\ln(1-y)=\ln x-\ln\left(1-\mathrm e^{\ln y}\right)=f(\ln x,\ln y)
$$

with

$$
f(u,v)=u-\ln\left(1-\mathrm e^v\right)=g(u)+h(v)\;.
$$

Then you can expand $f$ around $\left(\ln x',\ln y'\right)$, and since $f$ is a sum of a function of $u$ and a function of $v$, you don't need a full expansion in two variables, you can just expand $g(u)$ and $h(v)$:

\begin{align}
f(u,v)&=u-\ln\left(1-\mathrm e^{v'}\right)-\left.\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\ln\left(1-\mathrm e^v\right)\right|_{v=v'}\left(v-v'\right)+O\left(\left(v-v'\right)^2\right)\\
&=u-\ln\left(1-\mathrm e^{v'}\right)+\frac{\mathrm e^{v'}}{1-\mathrm e^{v'}}\left(v-v'\right)+O\left(\left(v-v'\right)^2\right)\\
&=\ln x-\ln\left(1-y'\right)+\frac{y'}{1-y'}\left(\ln y-\ln y'\right)+O\left(\left(\ln y-\ln y'\right)^2\right)\;.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you. However, I think you did not include the expansion of $g(u)$? That is, you should have a $(u-u')$ term?

Comment: @majmun: Yes, I skipped that because it's trivial because $g(u)$ is linear; you can replace $u$ by $u'+(u-u')$ and $\ln x$ by $\ln x'+(\ln x-\ln x')$.